# How to schedule a job on server in Java web application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, scheduled-tasks, sling

I am new to J2EE and i am working on couple of tasks. one of them is : 
I have a web application that works like a reporting toolbox hosted by Apache tomcat 7, I need a heavy weight job to be scheduled to run every hour or other intervals, I googled and find [Apache Sling](https://sling.apache.org/) that is kind of separate application server for content-centeric applications. I want to know if there is other solution could be done Apache tomcat or not ?
also its important that solution would be standard and reliable.

Comment: What is the scheduled task doing?

Comment: @Stefan it runs multiple queries on an oracle database and process on that resultset, process maybe run over 200K rows each time

Answer (score 1):

There's the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which is part of the standard java api. See the `new*Schedule*` factory methods in [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

For a more heavyweight / configurable option there's [Quartz](https://quartz-scheduler.org/). One of Quartz' nice features is it's support for [cron expressions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Comment: thanks for your response, does the Quartz gets integrated with tomcat ?

Comment: I'm not sure if quartz comes bundeled with a [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) or not. If it doesn't you'll need to create one and include it in your `web.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Spring Batch.  Here's a link that can help you understand this framework.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the packages work for you one option would be to implement a ServletContextListener. It is an object that is launched when your site goes online. The only problem is that you have to manage all the scheduling.